# How do I split apart each value in an array in python?

Tags: python

I have an array where each value is something like (5 , "d"), with an integer and then a string. I have lots of these in an array. How do I split each set of these into the integer and the string like 5 and "d"?

Comment: So you have an array of tuples? Please put the array you have and your expected output. Also, do you need to do it inplace or you can use another array to do this?

Comment: Can you post any code from any attempts you have?

Comment: I think you may be looking for `myInts, myStrings = zip(*myList)`, but it's really hard to tell without a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by "split"? Tuples are *already* split. Or do you have a string that looks like a tuple literal, like `'(5, "d")'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `zip`, as suggested in comments:

```
>>> myarr = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')]
>>> ints, strs = zip(*myarr)
>>> ints
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> strs
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
>>> list(ints)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> list(strs)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this If you like.

```
arr=[(1,"a"),(2,"b")]
ints=[i[0] for i in arr]
strings=[i[1] for i in arr]
print(ints,strings)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try list comprehensions as well.

```
myarr = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')]
ints = [x[0] for x in myarr]
strs =[x[1] for x in myarr]
```

This will create a list of integers and strings separately.